# Parse HTML/XML and find locations of elements in original document

Tags: python, xml-parsing, html-parsing, lxml

Is there a way to get the original location of an element in a document, ie. the start and end character index, when parsing html/xml in Python?

I've looked through the lxml documentation and couldn't find anything.

**eg.**

```
<a>1</a><b>2</b>
```

...

```
print tree.find('b').original_position
# result: (9, 16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google found [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t586608-is-there-a-html-parser-who-can-reconstruct-the-original-html-exactly.html), the gist of which is: it's hard for malformed documents because parsing requires synthesizing valid tokens that don't have any corresponding input.  It's possible for valid documents, but most parsing libraries don't support it.

Comment: I suspected something like this to be the case. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the character indices for all elements, attributes, tags, text, etc. in valid XML document using [Pawpaw](https://github.com/rlayers/pawpaw).

**Code:**

```
import sys
sys.modules['_elementtree'] = None
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pawpaw import xml
text = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
</data>"""
root = ET.fromstring(text, parser=xml.XmlParser())
for e in root.find('.//'):
    print(f'{e.tag}: {e.ito:%span}')
```

**Output:**

```py
rank: (72, 100)
year: (109, 126)
gdppc: (135, 156)
neighbor: (165, 205)
neighbor: (214, 258)
```