# Print HTML text of a selenium webelement in Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-scraping, urllib2

I am using Selenium webdriver in Python for a web-scraping project.

How to print the HTML text of the selenium.WebElement ?

I intend to use the `BeautifulSoup` to parse the HTML to extract the data of interest.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible to get the raw HTML from a `WebElement`.

You can get the page source from the browser object though: `browser.page_source`.

Comment: This question I asked covers the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8258529/311220